# Installing Ubuntu on a Toshiba cick mini

Tags: toshiba

I'm desperately trying to boot Ubuntu under my Toshiba Click Mini tablet, without any lucks.

I downloaded the `ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso` version and checked the quality with md5sum.

I disabled secure boot. Now, everytime I boot the tablet, I go into bitlocker and if I want to boot Windows, I have to enter the key from Microsoft

Here's my tries so far :

- I installed it in my USB key using LiveUSB Creator. Placed it on the tablet (via the keyboard) and selected "USB Key" from the bitlocker : no luck, it restarted and went to bitlocker again

  - I followed an [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/395880/123916) that says to only copy the iso into the disk and make it bootable, which I did. Same result : reboot in the bitlocker.

I don't know what to do. Do I have to disable TPM in the bios? Do I have to do something special to my usb key? I must say that the EFI/UEFI thingy makes me a bit lost :/

Thank you for your help.